# Writing a Fernet Key to a textfile yields a bytes string instead of ASCII String

Tags: python, csv, cryptography

I am trying to write a Fernet Key generated by using the python cryptography module(https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) into a .txt file. This .txt file is then read to retrieve the Key.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import csv
#Creates textfile if textfile has not been created
with open("Keys.txt", "w+") as csvfile:
    csvfile.close()
with open("Keys.txt","rU") as csvfile:
    reader=csv.reader(csvfile)
    KeyFound=0
    for row in reader:
        if len(row)>0:
            KeyFound=1
            Key=row
            print(Key)
        else:
            pass
    if KeyFound==0:
        Key = Fernet.generate_key()
        print(Key)
        print("Created Key")
        csvfile.close()
#Writing Key to textfile
if KeyFound==0:
    with open("Keys.txt", "w+") as csvfile:
        writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(Key)
        csvfile.close()
```

However when I run this code it yields a `bytes` string instead of the key.

Example: 
A Fernet Key : `b'jDyzNLo3aPD6-zFGVRnzMyBdyy93wQhemJ8QR4VH2I0='`
Is written as:
`106,68,121,122,78,76,111,51,97,80,68,54,45,122,70,71,86,82,110,122,77,121,66,100,121,121,57,51,119,81,104,101,109,74,56,81,82,52,86,72,50,73,48,61`

I would like the .txt file to contain the key: `b'jDyzNLo3aPD6-zFGVRnzMyBdyy93wQhemJ8QR4VH2I0='`

I have done some research in to this matter and I know that the `b'` denotes a bytes string, but I still do not know why it is represented as a list of byte numbers instead of  `b'jDyzNLo3aPD6-zFGVRnzMyBdyy93wQhemJ8QR4VH2I0='`

I know saving the Key to a .txt file may not be the most secure method of doing this, so any other methods are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because it is the intended behaviour. From Python csv [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

> Writer Objects
>
> Writer objects (DictWriter instances and objects returned by the
>   writer() function) have the following public methods. **A row must be an
>   iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects** and a dictionary
>   mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers (by passing them through
>   str() first) for DictWriter objects.

Try using a DictWriter (and DictReader)

```
with open("Keys.txt", "w+") as csvfile:
    headers = ['key']
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'key': b'jDyzNLo3aPD6-zFGVRnzMyBdyy93wQhemJ8QR4VH2I0='})
    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Remember that the key is being generated using `Key = Fernet.generate_key()` so write statement cannot be hardcoded.

Comment: @LyraOrwell I just don't have paramiko installed so I tested like that.

Comment: Just store your `Key` in a dict and pass the dict. Then `Key` becomes an unfortunate name because of dict keys but...